# How to store a file name ext into a map using the experimental c++ 2017 lib

Tags: c++, filesystems

So i've got a simple little program that I want to store the file extensions into a map. The error comes when I try and store the `d->path().extension();` into my map `data.insert(d->path().extension(),15);`. 15 is just a place holder for now I want to store the file ext as the key. I think the error is string is unknown to the std::experimental::filesystem.

This is the current error it throws: 
"std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=int, _Pr=std::less, _Alloc=std::allocator>]" matches the argument list

```
#include <map>
#include <regex>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem;
map<string,int> rscan2(path const& f,map<string, int> const& data, unsigned i = 0)
{
    //string indet(i, ' ');

    for (recursive_directory_iterator d(f), e; d != e; ++d)
    {
    data.insert(d->path().extension(),15);
        if (is_directory(d->status()))
            rscan2(d->path(), data, i + 1);
    }
    return data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    map<string, int> holdTheInfo;
    rscan2(".", holdTheInfo);
}
```

Comment: this isnt the complete error message, is it?

Comment: did you include `<string>` ?

Comment: I accidently left off the "Matches argument list" re added it at the top

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include <string>

Comment: `d->path().extension()` returns a `std::filesystem::path` not a `std::string`  source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it clarifies what the issue is but I still have no idea how to fix the issue. Even with the <string> added it still throws more errors

Comment: You declared the map (`rscan2`) as taking a `std::string` as the key type, then tried to insert the result of `d->path().extension()` as the key.  `d->path().extension()` returns a `std::filesystem::path` not a `std::string` so the map can't use it as the key.

Comment: Okay so I went and changed `rscan2` to `map<path,int>` and then tried to insert `path extension = d->path().extension(); data.insert<extension,0>;` and I get a non-standard syntax need to create a pointer '&'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` has many helper methods to convert to strings. Listing a few:

- [.string()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string)
- [.generic_string()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/generic_string)
- [.c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native)
- [operator string_type()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native)

But the actual problem is that `std::map::insert` doesn't receive a key and value as arguments, only values. So you should instead use `insert_or_assign` (since C++17):

```
data.insert_or_assign(d->path().extension(), 15);
```

And the `operator string_type()` will be called for the returned path, converting it to an actual string.

Comment: Since the map key type is a `std::string`, why would you use `.c_str()` instead of `.string()`? For that matter, I would expect passing the `path` as-is would work since it has an implicit conversion to `std::string`.